# How to find extrema for given implicit function of $(x,y,z)$ variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

Given the equation $$z^3 - 33xyz - 27 = 0,$$ 
we know that $z=z(x,y)$. As $z$ is function of both $x$ and $y$, I don't really know how to search for extremeum, because of three variables. I only solved for two variables. I tried with wolfram but some kind of skate park was a graphic solution.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Without some sort of restriction on the domain of $ \ z \ $ , the function has no global maximum or minimum.  In the equation $ \ z·(z^2-33xy) = 27 \ \ , $ allowing the factor $ \ z^2 - 33xy \ $ to approach zero then permits $ \ z \ $ to increase or decrease without limit.  The surface representing the implicit function then asymptotically approaches the quasi-hyperbolic cylinder $ \ z^2 = 33xy \ $ which extends infinitely in either vertical direction.  So the function has *no* global extrema.

The function also asymptotically approaches the $ \ xy-$plane, since for $ \ xy > 0 \ $ , allowing the product to grow without limit causes $ \ z \ $ to approach zero "from below" ( $ z^2 - 33xy \ $ being negative), while for $ \ xy < 0 \ $ , the function approaches zero "from above".

Using implicit differentiation, we can produce partial derivatives
$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \ [ \ z^3 \ - \ 33xyz \ ] \ = \ \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \ [ \ 27 \ ] \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 3z^2 · \frac{\partial z }{\partial x} \ - \ 33yz \ - \ 33xy · \frac{\partial z }{\partial x} \ =  \ 0  $$ $$ \Rightarrow \  \ \frac{\partial z }{\partial x} \  =  \ \frac{11yz}{z^2 \ - \ 11xy} \ \ , \ \ \text{and similarly} \  \  \frac{\partial z }{\partial y} \  =  \ \frac{11xz}{z^2 \ - \ 11xy} \ \ . $$
Since $ \ z \ $ never attains the value of zero, the first partial derivatives both equal zero only at the single critical point at $ \ x = y = 0 \ \ , $ where $ \ z^3 = 27 \ \Rightarrow \ z = 3 \ \ . $  In the neighborhood of $ \ (0,0,3) \ \ , $ the surface in the plane $ \ y = x \ $ is "concave upward" [ $ \  z·(z^2-33x^2) = 27 \ $ ] , while it is "concave downward" in the plane $ \ y = -x \ $ [ $ \  z·(z^2+33x^2) = 27 \ $ ] .  Thus, $ \ (0,0,3) \ $ is a **saddle point**. [Hence, your "skate park"...]

Views of the surface [in light blue] for $ \ z =  f(x,y) \ $ appear below, with the asymptotic surface $ \ z^2 = 33xy  \ $ shown in yellow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the implicit function theorem ?

**Setting**

$$g:(u,v,w) \to w^3 -33uvw -27 $$

**Requirement**

Visit [Introduction to implicit function theorem](http://www2.econ.iastate.edu/classes/econ500/hallam/documents/ImplicitFunction.pdf)

Comment: Apparently minus sign was not included before 33xyz expression. Sorry about that

Comment: No problem I going to adapt my answer.